# How to pass dictionary items to a function in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary

I am writing a custom helper to handle nested navigation menu. I am having some trouble with passing a set of arrays (or dictionary) to the function.

Below is the Razor call to the ActionMenuItem

```
@Html.ActionMenuItem("All Reports", "index", "report", "icon-bar-chart", "last", new {"title" = "Report 1", "action" = "report1"}, new {"title" = "Report 2", "action" = "report2"})
public static MvcHtmlString ActionMenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String linkText, String actionName, String controllerName, String iconType = null, string classCustom = null, params Dictionary<string, string> subMenu)
```

My function works well, up until the dictionary items. 
I am able to generate a single level menu, but trying to get it to work with nested menus.

Any help, and lessons is much appreciated!

Thank you,

RD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do something like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionMenuItem(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    String linkText,
    String actionName,
    String controllerName,
    String iconType = null,
    string classCustom = null,
    params KeyValuePair<string, string>[] subMenus)
{ ... }

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "a", "b" },
    { "c", "d" },
};

*.ActionMenuItem(*, *, *, *, *, dict.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked out well. It's a bit messy in the razor view, but I'll figure that out later.

Comment: How do I check if the dictionary is empty or null. Since the dictionary values are not required, there may be instances where its not passed.

I've tried to use subMenus != null, but it is returning true even when dictionary is not populated with any values...

any ideas?

Comment: Try `subMenus.Any()` to see if you have any parameters. Otherwise you just need to do a LINQ query to find the values you're after.

Comment: Thanks, I am using subMenus.Length > 0 to see if the dictionary pair is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` as parameter array using `params` keyword.

According to c# specification:

> A parameter declared with a `params` modifier is a parameter array. If a
>   formal parameter list includes a parameter array, it must be the last
>   parameter in the list and **it must be of a single-dimensional array
>   type**.

`Dictionary` is not *a single-dimensional array*.

You could create a class with two properties: `Title` and `Action` and change parameter type to `MyClass[]` instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    @Html.ActionMenuItem(
        "All Reports", 
        "index", 
        "report", 
        "icon-bar-chart", 
        "last", 
        new Dictionary<string, string>[]
        {
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "title", "Report 1" }, 
                { "action", "report1" }
            }, 
            new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "title",  "Report 2" },
                { "action", "report2" }
            }
        } )

    public static MvcHtmlString ActionMenuItem(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string linkText, 
        string actionName, 
        string controllerName, 
        string iconType = null, 
        string classCustom = null, 
        params Dictionary<string, string>[] subMenu)
```